# "perldoc -f" for Perl6/Rakudo

Tags: perl, documentation, raku

Does for Perl6/Rakudo already exist something like perl5's "perldoc -f function_name" for build-in-functions which gives me a short and quick usage instruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the tool you are looking for:

- [p6doc tool](https://github.com/perl6/doc) contains `-f` option
- [Online version](http://doc.perl6.org/)
- `perl6 --doc` option

If you don't have it installed, install it with `zef`:

```
zef install p6doc
```

If you don't have `zef` installed, install it from [zef's github repo](https://github.com/ugexe/zef).

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... This may not be exactly what you want, but:

[Perl6::Doc - all useful Perl 6 Docs in your command line](http://search.cpan.org/~lichtkind/Perl6-Doc/lib/Perl6/Doc.pm)

This includes `p6doc` command line utility, which can be used to read Synopses thusly:

```
p6doc s05    # Browse Synopsis 05
```

The full list of synopsis is available here: http://perlcabal.org/syn/ ; Perl 6's built-in functions is s29: http://perlcabal.org/syn/S29.html

I never saw an individual per-function documentation like `perldoc -f fname`, though.

---

Also, on a related note there's a [Periodic Table of Perl 6 operators](http://glyphic.s3.amazonaws.com/ozone/mark/periodic/Periodic%20Table%20of%20the%20Operators%20A4%20300dpi.jpg)

Comment: I tried this, but I get only an error-message: "If 'p6doc' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf p6doc". There is not much in my Doc.pm.

Comment: @sid - they may have removed the program from the latest (0.47) distribution - it was there in 0.36 one.

Comment: The Synopses don't look as bad as I thought they would be.

Answer (score 3):

The perl --doc is actually a red herring.

The command is "p6doc"

```
% p6doc
What documentation do you want to read?
Examples: p6doc Type::Str
          p6doc Type::Str.split

You can also look up specific method/routine definitions:
          p6doc -f push
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, **Perl6** doesn't come with a **perldoc** command. (Like Perl 5 in fact, even though most of Linux distributions, except Debian, come with a functional perldoc).

So you have to install it.

Following Perl6 documentation (`https://docs.perl6.org/programs/02-reading-docs`), you have to zef it.

```
zef install p6doc
```

... and on my **Centos**, it didn't work, because **p6doc** is installed in rakudo folder, not in a bin directory, groumpf.

So I ln it also :)

```
ln -s /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/site/bin/p6doc /usr/bin
```

Enjoy now, life in Perl world is always better with a perldoc at hand.